# (Django) Limited ForeignKey choices by Current User

Tags: python, django

**Update**

Thanks to Michael I was able to get this to work perfectly in my CreateView, but not in the UpdateView. When I try to set a form_class it spits out an improperly configured error.

How can I go about filtering the ForeignKey in the updateview?

**End Update**

I have a feeling I'm missing something small here but I've been working on it for a while and can't figure it out.

I have an app called story universe where the user creates one with a name and description.

I then have a character creator class where the user can create a character within that universe. This all works fine, except when the user goes to create their character they see a list of all universes created by all users.

Then there are other apps that will also mimic what I'm trying to do with the character creator.

I need to limit the Story Universes to only those created by the currently logged in user.

I've tried a few different ways and had the most success with the following, but with this code, no Universe appears when trying to create a new character.

`models.py`:

```
class Universe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='universe',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,default="")    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('universe:singleuniverse',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        unique_together = ['user','name']

class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='characters',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    universe = models.ForeignKey("story_universe.Universe", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('character_developer:singlecharacter',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['name']
        unique_together=['user','name']
```

`views.py`:

```
class CreateCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    template_name ='character_developer/character_create.html'
    form_class = CreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateCharacter,self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CreateForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['universe'].queryset = Character.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ('universe','name')
```

Comment: Hi Jermey, what happens when you change `self.fields['universe]` in `CreateForm` to `Universe.objects.filter(user=user)`?

Comment: Hmm, so I imported Universe class from the other app and changed as your suggestion and it seems to work.

I'll mess with it some more to be sure, but thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent - I've added it as my answer below. However, in your form, what do you see for your list of `Universes`? Do you see the "name" attribute of the `Universe`, or just some random `id` / primary key ?

Comment: I see the 'name' attribute

Comment: Perfect - and is that behaving as you want?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be exactly what I needed! I upvoted your answer below.

Comment: Many thanks, I upvoted your question as well to get you off the ground! (It's frustrating because you can't do much on low rep)

Comment: @MichealJRoberts this solution doesn't work for the UpdateView. Any idea how I can get the same filter in updateview?

I updated my initial post with this question as well.

Comment: Hi Jeremy - are you able to provide this in a new question and tag me in it...

Comment: @MichealJRoberts just did it, not sure if it tagged you but here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065617/django-limited-foreignkey-choices-by-current-user-in-updateview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a slight change to the `CreateForm` class in your `forms.py`:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CreateForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['universe'].queryset = Universe.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ('universe','name')
```

That will then pull through the returned `Universe` objects into the universe field, but only for the currently logged in user.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael! I imported the model and changed to your suggestion and it worked perfectly!