# (Django) Limited ForeignKey choices by Current User in UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I recently was able to figure out how to do this in the CreateView, but the same is not working for the UpdateView (Here's the original post on how to do it in the CreateView: [(Django) Limited ForeignKey choices by Current User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064478/django-limited-foreignkey-choices-by-current-user))

Essentially, I need it to display only the Universes created by the currently logged in user, but by default, it displays all universes. 
When I try to set a form_class and have it mimic the solution for CreatView, it spits out an improperly configured error.

`models.py`:

```
class Universe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='universe',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,default="")    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('universe:singleuniverse',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        unique_together = ['user','name']

class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='characters',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    universe = models.ForeignKey("story_universe.Universe", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('character_developer:singlecharacter',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['name']
        unique_together=['user','name']
```

`views.py`:

```
class UpdateCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
     model = Character
     fields = ('universe','name')
     template_name = 'character_developer/character_update_form.html'
```

**UPDATE** 
The error was:

Error: ImproperlyConfigured at /characters/update/3/
UpdateCharacter is missing a QuerySet. Define UpdateCharacter.model, UpdateCharacter.queryset, or override UpdateCharacter.get_queryset().

and here's what the code looked like to get the error:

views.py:

```
class UpdateCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'character_developer/character_update_form.html'
    form_class = UpdateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UpdateCharacter,self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(UpdateForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['universe'].queryset = Universe.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ('universe','name')
```

Comment: @MichealJRoberts any ideas?

Comment: Show the error and the code you used when you got that error.

Comment: Just edited the post to show. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need the following in your `views.py` (almost an exact extension of your CreateCharacter):

```
class UpdateCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Character
    template_name ='character_developer/character_create.html'
    form_class = UpdateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UpdateCharacter,self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I would caveat the above - make sure that the user instance in the request object is that of the currently logged in user, and has sufficient permission to update their own user - and can't somehow make a request on their behalf.

Comment: I don't think this would work since using the CreateView wouldn't allow the user to update, but instead create a new entry in the database, right? It would defeat the purpose of trying to update.

Comment: @JeremyCollier Note the inheritance from `generic.UpdateView`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try later tonight. I'm guessing the form.py should be the same as for the CreateView as well then?

Comment: @JeremyCollier Yes. theoretically you could use the same - I would rename `CreateForm` to `CreateOrUpdateCharacterForm` (and lose `UpdateForm` altogether as you'll be repeating code). I would recommend a specific `UpdateForm` if certain values are uneditable after Character creation/registration/sign-up.

Comment: @JeremyCollier Also, just to be pedantic - I wouldn't call your form `CreateForm` or `UpdateForm` - this is an ambiguous name. Use names such as `CreateUniverseForm`, or `UpdateCharacterForm`, or `UserLoginForm` etc etc (use the class name to describe what it does).

Comment: I'm still getting the error when trying to run this code 

"ImproperlyConfigured at /characters/update/3/
UpdateCharacter is missing a QuerySet. Define UpdateCharacter.model, UpdateCharacter.queryset, or override UpdateCharacter.get_queryset()."

Comment: I figured it out. Another Google search showed that you have to have model = Character in the view as well as the form class. Adding that fixed it and your provided code works. If you could change your answer to reflect that I'll 
 mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: @JeremyCollier Doh! Yes, apologies, I missed this bit out! Typing too fast I think XD Glad it helped and worked. I've edited my question to take include the model parameter, could you please mark it off as the correct answer when you get a chance! :D

Comment: Will do, and thank you again! I may be seeking you out for help in the future ^_^

Comment: @JeremyCollier No worries - glad to help a fellow Django-er! :)